# How to plot fitted model over observed time series

Tags: r, plot

This is a really really simple question to which I seem to be entirely unable to get a solution. I would like to do a scatter plot of an observed time series in R, and over this I want to plot the fitted model.

So I try something like:

```
model <- lm(x~y+z)
plot(x)
lines(fitted(model))
```

But this just plots x with lines.

Thanks

Comment: You're missing a ')' on the third line of code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you want `abline(model)` here as in this example from the help page:

```
 z <- lm(dist ~ speed, data = cars)
 plot(cars)
 abline(z) # equivalent to abline(reg = z) or
 abline(coef = coef(z))
```

Comment: doesn't work. For one thing, I get an error saying that it can only use the first 2 regression coefficients (I have 4)

Comment: That's special case.  Exactly how do you expect to plot a response over four dependents?  Five-dimensional plots are hard...  So what is often done is to fix n-1 of these at some value (say their mean) and then vary the n-th along with response variable. That way you get several charts of y versus the different x_i.

Comment: I don't really need all that, all I need is for the vector of fitted values (which I already have) to be plotted on a line.

So I suppose I can just say that what I am asking is, if I have time series x, and time series y, then how do I plot both on the same graph, where x is a scatter plot, and y is a line graph.

Comment: plot( fitted(mymodel), type='l')   -- if you don't provide an x vector, the sequence is used. If you have an x vector, use plot(x, fitted(mymodel), type='l')

Answer (score 5):

```
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100)
z <- rnorm(100)

model <- lm(x~y+z)
plot(x,type="l",col="green")
lines(fitted(model),col="blue")
```

I tried this and it seems to work

Answer (score 0):

Another opportunity:

```
n = 100; mi = 0; sigma = 2
x = rnorm(n,mi,sigma)
e = rnorm(n,0,1)
b0 = 1; b1 = 2
y = b1*x + b0 + e
#plot observations
plot(x,y)
#model
lm_res= lm(y~x)
summary(lm_res)
arg= c(min(x),max(x))
out = coef(lm_res)[2]*arg+ coef(lm_res)[1]
#plot model line
lines(arg, out, col = 'red')
```